Nav Links stop working when i change height of banner
My banner needs to be smaller only for this specific page, when I tried to use css inline it did change the height to what i needed it to be but my links stopped working.
This is the code on my css file:
/* Nav User Page*/
.nav-borders .nav-link.active {
  text-decoration-color: #dc3030;
  border-bottom-color: #dc3030;
  color: #dc3030; 
}

.nav-borders .nav-link.active b {
  color: #dc3030; 
}

.nav-borders .nav-link {
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom-width: 0.125rem;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

/*Banner and Header*/
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.banner-area {
  background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg) center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner-area .overlay-bg {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.banner-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
  text-align: center;
  
}

#header {
  padding: 0px 0px 14px 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
}

#header hr {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.header-top {
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-top a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

And this is the code HTML, that was working perfectly before I changed my banner height:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx" class="no-js">
<head>
        <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/fav.png">
        <!-- Author Meta -->
        <meta name="author" content="codepixer">
        <!-- Meta Description -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- Meta Keyword -->
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <!-- meta character set -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- Site Title -->
        <title>User Page</title>

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <!--
        CSS
        ============================================= -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/linearicons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.css">                  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
       
    </head>
    <body>

      <header id="header" id="home" >
        <div class="container header-top">

                  <div class="logo">
                  
            <div id="logo">
              <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
          </div>
            </div>
            <nav id="nav-menu-container">
              <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="menu-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">Sobre nós</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Eventos</a></li>
                <li><a href="event.html">Doações</a></li>
                <li><a href="ticket.html">Propostas</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog-home.html">Contactos</a><li>
                <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Artistas</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="blog-single.html">Adriana Bárbara</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category.html">Maria Venceslau</a></li>
                    <li><a href="elements.html">Laura Gonçalves</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category.html">Concha carvalho</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category.html">Zé Dias </a></li>
                    <li><a href="category.html">André Vaz</a>
                    </li></li>
                  </ul>
                      <li><a 
                          
                      
                      <div class="navbar-user">
                          <a href="index.html">
                              <img src="img/Simbolo.svg" alt="Usuário" />
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  
                                  
              </ul>
            </nav><!-- #nav-menu-container -->                  
          </div>
      </div>
    </header><!-- #header -->

    <!-- start banner Area -->
    <section class="banner-area relative" id="home" style="height: 150px;"> 
      <div class="overlay overlay-bg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="about-content col-lg-12">               
            </div>                                          
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End banner Area -->

    <!-- Start Page Content Area -->  

      <!-- Nav Profile: Options -->
      <div class="container px-3 mt-3">
        <nav class="nav nav-borders">
          <a class="nav-link active ms-0" href="perfil.html" target="__self" > <b>Perfil</b></a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="propostas_perfil.html" target="__self" > <b>Propostas</b></a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="doacoes_perfil.html" target="_self" > <b>Doações</b></a>
        </nav>

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it! And if needed, I'll provide the full extent of the code, but I am sure that the error is here.
The links were working perfecty before I made this small change.
Thank you in advance!

It appears you have an HTML fragment that is messing things up in the code you provided. In this section there's an extra <li><a, not sure how to point it out to you. It was on line 68 of my code editor.
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li class="menu-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Sobre nós</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Eventos</a></li>
            <li><a href="event.html">Doações</a></li>
            <li><a href="ticket.html">Propostas</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog-home.html">Contactos</a><li>
            <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Artistas</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="blog-single.html">Adriana Bárbara</a></li>
                <li><a href="category.html">Maria Venceslau</a></li>
                <li><a href="elements.html">Laura Gonçalves</a></li>
                <li><a href="category.html">Concha carvalho</a></li>
                <li><a href="category.html">Zé Dias </a></li>
                <li><a href="category.html">André Vaz</a>
                </li></li>
              </ul>
                  <li><a 
                      
                  
                  <div class="navbar-user">
                      <a href="index.html">
                          <img src="img/Simbolo.svg" alt="Usuário" />
                      </a>
                  </div>
              
                              
          </ul>
        </nav>


Hi! Thank you. I've fixed that, but the links still don't work.

What happens when you click on them?

Nothing. It is as if they are just normal text

Could you re-post the code for the entire html page so I can review it? or a GitHub link? I want to review the whole page.
